# I would be interested in reading about (blank) in a Community Blog!

Tags: discussion

Please upvote the question if you would read a community blog.

Upvote an answer or add your own answer indicating your interest in a particular topic.

Answer (score 8):

In-Depth Strategy - A deep analysis of strategy for a particular game.

Answer (score 4):

Product Review - If you suffer from the disease of the cult of the new, you might want to have  access to product reviews. It wouldn't have to be games that are brand new, although this is probably the most useful for other users. If we could produce work half as good as [EndersGame](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/364975/a-comprehensive-pictorial-overview-ra-ra-ra-knizia), we should be lucky.

Answer (score 3):

Game Design - This might just be wishful thinking, but I hope there are enough game designer enthusiasts that are willing to share their thought process in designing a game.

Answer (score 2):

Session Reports - A weekly or bi-weekly report about how a game turned out. Perhaps with pictures or video of the game play to help people follow it. Either described from the point of view of a all knowing being, or from the perspective of a single player.

Answer (score 2):

Best of Board and Card Games - Take the most thought provoking and/or popular Q&A and transform the best few answers into blog posts. For example, a strategy question that results in separate strategies for an answer spread across 4 good answers could have all the 4 answers blended into a single blog post.

Comment: Isn't this a sign that the answers ought to be refined into a more authoritative one?

Comment: @AlexP Sometimes the answers need to be refined more as you say. But sometimes there's simply a diversity of answers. Here's an example where there's not only diverse answers, but IMO the "wisdom of the crowd" was flat out wrong and could use the helpful commentary of an experienced player to lend more perspective to the answers: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1018/how-to-start-in-catan-games

Answer (score 1):

Game Theory/Game Tech - Discussions about game mechanics, or general game theory concepts. For an idea of what this might look like, see [Ludology - Geoff Engelstein](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/ludology/id419046224). He has a running segment on The Dice Tower where he discusses Game Theory.